# AngularJS: How to filter based on the closest distance of post code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, angularjs

I face a tough requirement from my client is that we need to filter the addresses of company based on the postcode. For example, there are about 5 companies with postcode 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015 and 2020. Then when the users type in text-field value 2019, then the result should be 2020, 2015, 2010, 2005, 2000.

At this moment, I'm using AngularJS filter based on the text-field postcode, but it just filters based on matching the exact keyword.

For example: When I type 2020, it displays 1 result with the address of 2020 while it should be: 2020, 2015, 2010, 2005, 2000. And the tough one is with 2019 keyword, it displays nothing while it should be 2020, 2015.

Finally, another requirement is to display the distance for each company based on the input postcode.

JSON values I'm filtering is:

```
[
 {"CompanyName": "ABC", "Address": "XYZ", "PostCode": "2000"},
 {"CompanyName": "ABD", "Address": "XYYZZ", "PostCode": "2020"},
 {"CompanyName": "ABE", "Address": "XXYYZ", "PostCode": "2015"}, 
 ...
]
```

I'm really struggling with this and hope someone could help me with this. I'm really appreciate it.

**Update**
Thanks @Luze26. This really displayed what I described. And I used the mathematical distance between 2 postCode to display as the area distance. But after I searched on google map, then I realize (and according to @doldt) the mathematical distance between postCode doesn't represent the distance between areas of those postCode. I thought they were the same :). Really apologize for my misunderstanding. I'm still looking for the right solution and appreciate it if there's any from others and thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the `orderBy` filter from Angular with a function returning the distance to the input post code.

You can see the jsfiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13149/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to do this server side by using geolocation data for each zipcode. Then you can do a distance query and set your limits.

The data can be obtained from USPS. There are roughly 80,000 zipcodes

Comment: In my understanding, he's only looking for a plain mathematical distance between the zip codes, not geographical.

Comment: @dolt there still needs to be data for that. The actual zipcode number alone won't help. And what is the difference between mathematical distance and geographical distance?

Comment: @charlieftl I don't mean mathematical distance between the areas the zip codes represent, just the plain difference of the zip codes themselves as numbers :)

Comment: create a simple custom filter then

Answer (score 0):

There are client-side services for calculating the distance between two postal codes. Here is one that my coworker wrote: https://github.com/TheBosZ/geocoder-service

I hope this helps!